# Добавление новых операций в Python (например ***)

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, классы, методы

а можно создать новое действие для класса в Python?
Например какой-то магический метод который вызывается при `***` или `*--`
Например:

```
a = Foo(2)
b = Foo(3)
print(a *** b)
```

И в классе `Foo` вызывался какой-нибудь **магический метод** и обрабатывал это?
Например:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, q):
        self.q = q
    def __(Что то)__(self, other):
        return (self.q + 1) * (other.q + 2)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/932328/7485582

Comment: Если коротко, то нет, без изменения кода самого интерпретатора это не возможно сделать.

Comment: Жаль, но всё равно спасибо)

Comment: А мне вот интересно как вы пришли к этому вопросу? В Python что то не реализовано?

Answer (score 0):

Нет, к сожалению вы не можете добавлять новые операторы в Python.

Но есть альтернатива. Вы можете добавлять функции к классу, и использовать их в дальнейшем. Не синтаксический сахар, но всё же.

```
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, q):
        self.q = q

    def triple_multiply(self, other):
        return (self.q + 1) * (other.q + 2)
```

И используем:

```
a = Foo(2)
b = Foo(3)
print(a.triple_multiply(b))
```